# Why, does it seem, that I need to use two double quotes to delimit file paths?

Tags: python, string, shell, path

I'm writing a script in python that runs a program. Spaces in the path or arguments need to be quoted, but for some reason it won't seem to work unless I use double quoted strings e.g.

```
  DEFAULT_CLIENT = '""C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin""'
  command =('stjava.exe -autologon -is -p ""'+src+'"" -fp ""'+dst+'"" '
            '-filter "OI" "*" -f ""'+dst+'/config/bc.stjava""')
  if not "StarTeam Cross-Platform Client" in os.getenv("PATH"):
    print "[INFO] Star Team Client not found in path defaulting to: "+DEFAULT_CLIENT
    command = DEFAULT_CLIENT+"/"+command
  os.system(command)
```

Why is this? If I am doing something wrong here then how should I be doing it?

**[Update]** When calling `os.system(command)` This finds the application correctly:

```
  command = r'"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin/stjava.exe" '
  command += '-autologon -is -p '
```

But this doesn't:

```
  command = '"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin/stjava.exe" '
  command += '-autologon -is -p '
  command += '"C:\a\b c\d"'
```

It says 'C:\Program' is not a recognised command. The paths in the arguments seems to be an issue, but I don't know why.

Comment: Can you please show the actual string which didn't work for you?

Comment: Sure, here: '"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin"'

Comment: What is the expected output string? You can use os.sep for path separator.

Answer (score 0):

**Initial answer:**

You want `C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin/stjava.exe` to be your full binary path, right ?
As the path has spaces in it, quotes are necessary.

Using single quotes, after concatenation it will be something like: `"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin"stjava.exe`.

Have you tried to use proper file-path separators ?

**As you added some more information, I have another suggestion:**

I see that the last parameter in your command string contains backslash characters. Those proved to be problematic in many situations. Can you try to escape those, or double them, into something like `"C:\\a\\b c\\d"`?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need following line as command

```
'"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin/stjava.exe" -autologon -is -p "abc def" -fp "aa bb" -filter "OI" "*" -f "aa bb/config/bc.stjava"'
```

which you can achieve by following:

```
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> DEFAULT_CLIENT = '"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin"'
>>> 
>>> DEFAULT_CLIENT
'"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin"'
>>> 
>>> src = "abc def"
>>> dst = "aa bb"
>>> 
>>> 
>>> command =('stjava.exe" -autologon -is -p "'+src+'" -fp "'+dst+'" -filter "OI" "*" -f "'+dst+'/config/bc.stjava"')
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> DEFAULT_CLIENT[:-1] + os.sep + command
'"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin/stjava.exe" -autologon -is -p "abc def" -fp "aa bb" -filter "OI" "*" -f "aa bb/config/bc.stjava"'
>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that wasn't it. Problem seems to be with the arguments - I updated my question.

Comment: Oho OK. In that case I would suggest you to debug further. Does the command works without any parameters? I mean what happens if you do os.system(r'"C:/Program Files/Borland/StarTeam SDK 14.0/bin/stjava.exe" '). Can you check subprocess.call also?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb and say that, for some reason, the command-line parser you are using or the Windows or DOS command line interpreter needs quoted file names to have "escaped quotation marks".  I tried various combinations with the DOS DIR command with zero, one, and two double quotes and it worked every time.